# Installing ssdeep package from PyPi on M1 Macbook

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1, pypi

## The Goal

Install [ssdeep](https://pypi.org/project/ssdeep/) PyPi package on a M1 Macbook Pro.

## The Problem

When I run `pip install ssdeep` I get 2 errors

The first error is caused because `fuzzy.h` cannot be found.

```
warnings.warn(
  running egg_info
  creating /private/var/folders/0f/4c82tsj50n10zqq89fndcslc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ai0atrdv/ssdeep.egg-info
  writing /private/var/folders/0f/4c82tsj50n10zqq89fndcslc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ai0atrdv/ssdeep.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/0f/4c82tsj50n10zqq89fndcslc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ai0atrdv/ssdeep.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to /private/var/folders/0f/4c82tsj50n10zqq89fndcslc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ai0atrdv/ssdeep.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/0f/4c82tsj50n10zqq89fndcslc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ai0atrdv/ssdeep.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/0f/4c82tsj50n10zqq89fndcslc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ai0atrdv/ssdeep.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  src/ssdeep/__pycache__/_ssdeep_cffi_a28e5628x27adcb8d.c:266:14: fatal error: 'fuzzy.h' file not found
      #include "fuzzy.h"
                ^~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/user/proj/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 186, in _compile
      self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] + extra_postargs)
    File "/Users/user/proj/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py", line 1007, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/user/proj/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/spawn.py", line 70, in spawn
      raise DistutilsExecError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

The second error has to do with setuptools.installer being deprecated. I'm not sure this is all that important though. I think resolving the first error would resolve this one as well.

```
/Users/user/proj/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
```

## Attempted Solutions

**Solution 1:** Install SSDeep with Homebrew `brew install ssdeep`

**Result:** `pip install ssdeep` has the same error about fuzzy.h missing

**Solution 2:** Use the prepackaged version of SSDeep `BUILD_LIB=1 pip install ssdeep`

**Result**: The error about `fuzzy.h` goes away but the second error regarding `setuptools.installer` being deprecated remains.

## References

- [Compiling SSDeep and pydeep on MacOS X 10.9+](http://wzr.github.io/blog/2014/10/06/compiling-ssdeep-and-pydeep-on-mac-os-x-10-dot-9-plus/) This was pretty out of date though.
- [SSDeep Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ssdeep/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Essentially what's going on is that Homebrew installs ssdeep in a location that the ssdeep PyPi package is not expecting. You can point the PyPi package to the correct locations with the following steps.

1: Install ssdeep with homebrew `brew install ssdeep`

2: List homebrew directories for ssdeep `brew ls ssdeep`
This produces output like

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/bin/ssdeep
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/include/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/lib/libfuzzy.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/lib/ (2 other files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/share/man/man1/ssdeep.1
```

3: Set the `LDFLAGS` environment variable to the path of the ssdeep lib directory from the output in step 2.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/lib"
```

4: Set the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable to the path of the ssdeep include directory from the output in step 2.

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/include
```

5: Install ssdeep from PyPi `pip install ssdeep`

Comment: I tried this solution, the installation was successful. However, when I try to use the library, it gives the error "no module named ssdeep"

Comment: Can you run ssdeep from command line? `ssdeep -V`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have figured out the problem. I followed this method and it installed the library to Python 3.11, meanwhile my default python3 is running Python 3.9. If I run python3.11 I no longer have this error.

Answer (score 3):

@HopAlongPolly answer almost worked for me but i got an error which the root cause seems to be:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ssdeep/2.14.1/lib/libfuzzy.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
```

to solve this i ran `BUILD_LIB=1 pip install ssdeep`

If your env is pretty new you will get the following errors:

```
/bin/sh: libtoolize: command not found
/bin/sh: automake: command not found
```

to solve this you need to run `brew install libtool automake` and then create the following a symlink somewhere in your path from libtoolize to the glibtoolize binary that was installed via brew (This is needed as build process looks for libtoolize but homebrew installs glibtoolize). Pretty sure there is a cleaner way to point to the correct binary but the symlink did the job ;)

In summary do the steps that @HopAlongPolly recommended then run

```
brew install libtool automake
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/glibtoolize /opt/homebrew/bin/libtoolize
BUILD_LIB=1 pip install ssdeep
```

Comment: Note that my environment installed to `/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize` and so made the adjustment to your softlink command above

Answer (score 0):

`ssdeep` package at PyPI is a Python wrapper for `ssdeep` library written in C. So first you have to [compile and install `ssdeep`](https://ssdeep-project.github.io/ssdeep/usage.html#install), then [other python-ssdeep requirements](https://python-ssdeep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#requirements), then compile and install `python-ssdeep`.

Comment: For clarification do I need to install OS packages for cffi, libfuzzy etc. or are these supposed to be other PyPi packages?

Comment: CFFI can be installed from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/cffi/#files). `libfuzzy` seems to be an OS package.